# If $x'=Ax$ and $y'=Ay$, does it mean that $x=y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The textbook says that the statement $x = y$ is False for this situation. Though I can't seem to understand it.

I put my understanding of the process of solving a system of differential equations by matrix diagonalization at the end, in case there is a flaw in my understanding. I wouldn't want you to read through proofs you may already know, especially if answering the question doesn't involve thinking about it. My thought process is this:

My conclusion from the process of solving a system of differential equations is that the entire process involves working with the matrix $A$, which is I assume equal in both systems of differential equations given in the question. The generation solution obtained seem to be purely reliant on this coefficient matrix $A$. So shouldn't the general solution be the same format for $x$ and $y$? There isn't any initial value given, so I don't think that the varying coefficients have anything to do with the $x=y$ statement. It seems we are only comparing the general solutions of $x$ and $y$. Is there something fundamental to this question that I'm not understanding or have skipped over? Perhaps the relationship between the $x$ and $y$ variables? I'm just not getting it.
$--------------------------------------$

Here I will put my understanding of the process of solving a system of differential equations by matrix diagonalization (as I learned through the textbook):

Involves first finding an invertible matrix $P$ that diagonalizes matrix $A$. To do this, the first step is to find the eigenvalues, and then eigenvectors of $A$, by:

$$det(λI - A) = 0$$
Making sure that there are an n amount of them (for the $n\times n$ matrices $x$ and $y$). This gives the matrix $P$ which has the eigenvectors as its columns. Then we can compute the diagonal matrix $D$, 
$$D = P^-1AP = $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
λ_1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & λ_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & λ_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$$$
(for a $3 \times 3$ matrix, not sure how to properly format it for an nxn matrix without it looking like a mess, since I'm new to this)

We created a new unknown vector $u$ that is related to the unknown vector $y$ by: $y=Pu$:

$$y'=Ay$$
$$(Pu)'=A(Pu)$$
$$Pu'=APu$$
$$(P^-1)Pu'=(P^-1)APu$$
$$u'=(P^-1AP)u$$
$$u'=Du$$

Then we can solve the system for $u$. Once we do that, we can then solve for $y$ by $$y = Pu$$ since we got the matrix $P$ from the eigenvectors we determined for matrix $A$.

This brings us the general solution for our system of differential equations. Coming back to my point, if the general solution is obtained by manipulating the coefficient matrix $A$, which is equal for both systems given, then shouldn't the general solutions of $x'=Ax$ and $y'=Ay$ be equal regardless of what variable ($x$ or $y$) we use for the system?

Comment: Initial conditions can be different.

Comment: The solution is unique up to a constant vector. If you give the same initial conditions, the solution will be unique.

Comment: Forget matrices, look at the situation in dimension one. If $x'=17x$, and $y'=17y$, then you could have $x=e^{17t}$, and $y=42e^{17t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since matrix multiplication and differentiation are both linear, then whenever $x$ is a solution, $y=cx$ will be a different solution for any constant $c.$ If given initial conditions, we'll find that $c$ has to be $1,$ but without it, we have a family of different solutions.